# Xamarin.Forms generate .a static library for Android/iOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want try Xamarin.Forms for developing **static** library, which include: gui (activity for Android/storyboard for iOS) and mini - business logic. I downloaded module Xamarin.Forms for Visual Studio (windows) and create simple project Xamarin.Forms. He is include library-dll, which is shared projects Android and iOS, and Android app, and iOS app. I compiled project for Android and this is successed. But, shared library for Android and iOS have expansion *.dll, but not *.so(Android) or *.dylib(iOS). I checked, at compilation dll library converting to *.so and pack to apk (Android). Probably, same is happening at compiling application for iOS. I want compiling shared library for Android and iOS to static library *.a, for Android for four arch (arm64-v8a, armebi-v7, a, x86, x86_64) and iOS(armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64). Why do I need it? I already have apk (big project) and ipa (big project), and start development based on Xamarin.Forms will take al many time. Possible it? If compilation static library real, then how call code of static library on Android (java or c++) and iOS (obj-c or c++ or swift).
Thanks!

P.S.: if compiling in static library impossible, then how compiling dynamic library (Android and iOS)?

Comment: As i know, we could only generate .dll file with visual studio. .a file is generated with XCode.

Comment: Good. How I can open project from visual studio with my library in XCode? After all it is impossible.

Comment: For more details of XCode, you could check the link below. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CreatingProjects.html